# Joomla 3 Media Manager Permissions

Tags: joomla-3.x, acl, media-manager

Let me try and explain this as best I can. I am building a custom component that is used to manage a group of shows, just one component and each show is an item within this component.

For example, let's take "Blacktown Show", within the component a user gets assigned to each of the roles, ie president, secretary and treasurer. Again let's take users 1, 2 and 3 are part of the executive of that show.

On the front end each show will have its own page. I have created a permission of edit.own.show Which will see if the logged in user is associated with the show and if they are it will allow editing on the front end only.

My trouble is the media manager, will the media manager allow me to install a folder in images called Blacktown when the Blacktown show is created then if the user has permission to edit their own show it will only allow them to upload and change images in the Blacktown folder? I'm not sure how to assign permissions in the media manager for this situation because it's still the same component.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think you'd typically use media/com_mycomponent/blacktown_show/ or some such to store the images if you want to have access control. Then build your own UI to upload and change images in the folder that understands your access rules.

Comment: Have a look here maybe: https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/media-manager-acl/